# What sort of malware is this? Is my wallet compromised?

Tags: mist, wallets

Received a malware type desktop notification (not web) that had my address on there. Is my wallet compromised? Should I change wallets? I was using mist wallet.[image]

Comment: Does not look good. Check your Mist binaries. And on a clean computer, move your ETH to another account. The hard-fork has not required any passwords to be reset or accounts to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Without the binary being assessed or submitted to Virus Total its hard to say what type of malware it is.

It is clearly malware software like this from my knowledge was never created from the ethereum project.